# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code when archiving

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I have my flutter app, I am able to build it and run on my iphone but when I try to archive it to upload to test flight i get this errors :

```
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cujzpewjolforngnoxyherjuheln/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-AF6B532C04771866E7662848.sh (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    cd /Users/user/Documents/mdb-flutter-app/frontend/ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cujzpewjolforngnoxyherjuheln/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-AF6B532C04771866E7662848.sh

mkdir -p /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cujzpewjolforngnoxyherjuheln/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks
Symlinked...
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/openssl_grpc.framework" "/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cujzpewjolforngnoxyherjuheln/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Users/user/Documents/mdb-flutter-app/frontend/ios/../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/openssl_grpc.framework" failed: No such file or directory (2)
done

sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/97f6331a-ba75-11ed-a4bc-863efbbaf80d/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

**Showing Recent Issues**

```
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/97f6331a-ba75-11ed-a4bc-863efbbaf80d/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) \[sender=2.6.9\]
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APrKA.jpg)

```
Flutter clean  
Pods install --repo-update  
Pods deintegrate
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this solution (it works for me):

There is an issue with Cocoapods now, because Xcode 14.3 is now using a relative path in its symlink for frameworks.

Either wait for release of Cocoapods version 1.12.1 or make this simple change in your Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh file

You can find it on path:
"ios\Pods\Target Support Files\Pods-Runner\Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh"

**Replace:**

```
if [ -L "${source}" ]; then
echo "Symlinked..."
source="$(readlink "${source}")"
```

with:

```
if [ -L "${source}" ]; then
echo "Symlinked..."
source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
```

** Note that -f was added.

Then you can archive it and upload your app.

Comment: This worked in my case. But whenever I rebuild the app, it reverses Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh file back. To make this persistent between builds, you can follow the instructions here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11808#issuecomment-1500907375

Basically, you change the Podfile so instead of manually changing .sh file, it appends -f flag while building.

Comment: not worked for native ios

Answer (score 13):

As suggested by Ali Al-Amrad, I upgraded to Cocoapods version 1.12.1 using command:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then, I had to reinstall my project pods:

```
pod deintegrate; pod install
```

Comment: It did not work, the only solution was to modify Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh as described in the answer provided by Ali Al-Amrad

Answer (score 3):

The solution provided by @Ali Al-Armad is working perfectly. but. the issue with this is that. every time you have to change it manually.

add this script below so you don't need to change it every time.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    shell_script_path = "Pods/Target Support Files/#{target.name}/#{target.name}-frameworks.sh"
    if File::exists?(shell_script_path)
      shell_script_input_lines = File.readlines(shell_script_path)
      shell_script_output_lines = shell_script_input_lines.map { |line| line.sub("source=\"$(readlink \"${source}\")\"", "source=\"$(readlink -f \"${source}\")\"") }
      File.open(shell_script_path, 'w') do |f|
        shell_script_output_lines.each do |line|
          f.write line
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

credit for the change goes to [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11808#issuecomment-1500907375)