# After updating Xcode and trying to run an Archive build: 'Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code'

Tags: xcode, xcode14

After updating to the most recent version of Xcode, I tried running an Archive build, but it errors out before completion. I've tried:

```
- Deleting Podfile.lock file
- Deleting Pods file
- Deleting .xcworkspace file
- Running pod install again
- Clean Build Folder
```

Not sure how to fix this, but none of these solutions worked...

```
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_Project-################/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/My\Project/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/My\ Project.build/Release-iphoneos/My\ Project.build/Script-##############.sh (in target 'My Project' from project 'My Project')
    cd /Users/nickbrinsmade/Desktop/My\ Project
    /bin/sh -c /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_Project-###################/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/My\\\ Project/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/My\\\ Project.build/Release-iphoneos/My\\\ Project.build/Script-###############.sh

mkdir -p /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_Project-##################/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/My Project/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/My Project.app/Frameworks
Symlinked...
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Alamofire.framework" "/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_Project-##################/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/My Project/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/My Project.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Users/myuser/Desktop/My Project/../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Alamofire.framework" failed: No such file or directory (2)
done

sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/#######-####-####-####-#######/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

From matt's answer, this was printed to console when I ran 'pod deintegrate':

```
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
Ignoring bindex-0.8.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bindex --version 0.8.1
Ignoring bootsnap-1.7.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bootsnap --version 1.7.4
Ignoring byebug-11.1.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine byebug --version 11.1.3
Ignoring ffi-1.15.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.0
Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
Ignoring msgpack-1.4.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine msgpack --version 1.4.2
Ignoring nio4r-2.5.7 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nio4r --version 2.5.7
Ignoring pg-1.2.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine pg --version 1.2.3
Ignoring puma-5.2.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine puma --version 5.2.2
Ignoring racc-1.5.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine racc --version 1.5.2
Ignoring sassc-2.4.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine sassc --version 2.4.0
Ignoring websocket-driver-0.7.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine websocket-driver --version 0.7.3
```

Comment: I would suggest that you quit Xcode, throw out the entire DerivedData folder, restart the computer, `pod deintegrate`, `pod install`, and see what happens.

Comment: Just tried that, updating my answer with what was printed to the console when I tried to run the 'pod deintegrate' command.

Comment: @matt forgot to tag you

Comment: OK so your problem is probably that you are using the system ruby. If so: Don't.

Comment: Sorry, I don't even ever remember installing ruby to my computer. What do I have to run here? Just uninstall ruby from the system? @matt

Comment: "I don't even ever remember installing ruby to my computer" Correct, that's what I'm suggesting is the source of the problem. What you were doing was always wrong, and now you're busted. You need your _own_ ruby. You need to install your own ruby, then install the cocoapods gem to _that_ ruby, and so on. See for example the comment link and answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67445542/error-installing-cocoapods-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension (of which this might be a duplicate).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code when archiving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75928909/command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code-when-archiving)

Answer (score 0):

Open your project by Xcode and Go to **Pods->Target Support Files->Pods-YourProjectName-Frameworks**

Find out code block

```
if [ -L "${source}" ]; then
echo "Symlinked..."
source="$(readlink "${source}")"
fi
```

Replace source="$(readlink "${source}")" by **source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"**

Now you can archive your project in Xcode 15

[image]